# bokeh saveTool default file name save as bokeh_plot

Tags: javascript, python, plot, bokeh

I am using bokeh library to create plot and I used the built in tool that come with bokeh , the **issue **is with the save tool when I click on it it save the image with default name "bokeh_plot" I want to change it and i am struggling with that any help

I try the method inside this [Bokeh Custom Save Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358427/bokeh-custom-save-tool/48807936#48807936) i just change the filename to name since it give me that expected property is name and I import String from this
from bokeh.core.properties import String
and it still not working it give me error like that

```
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:3 - error TS1127: Invalid character.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
    ~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:5 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
      ~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:10 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
           ~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:13 - error TS1434: Unexpected keyword or identifier.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
              ~~~~~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:22 - error TS1434: Unexpected keyword or identifier.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
                       ~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:27 - error TS1434: Unexpected keyword or identifier.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
                            ~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:31 - error TS1434: Unexpected keyword or identifier.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
                                ~~~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:38 - error TS1228: A type predicate is only allowed in return type position for functions and methods.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:8:10 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

8   doit: () ->
           ~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:8:13 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

8   doit: () ->
              ~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:9:5 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

9     @plot_view.save(@model.save_name)
      ~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:9:21 - error TS1135: Argument expression expected.

9     @plot_view.save(@model.save_name)
                      ~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:9:37 - error TS1146: Declaration expected.

9     @plot_view.save(@model.save_name)
 
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:12:3 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

12   default_view: NewSaveView
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:12:15 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

12   default_view: NewSaveView
                 ~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:13:3 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

13   type: "CustomSaveTool"
     ~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:13:7 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

13   type: "CustomSaveTool"
         ~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:15:3 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

15   tool_name: "Save"
     ~~~~~~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:15:12 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

15   tool_name: "Save"
              ~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:16:3 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

16   icon: "bk-tool-icon-save"
     ~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:16:7 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

16   icon: "bk-tool-icon-save"
         ~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:18:3 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

18   @define { save_name: [ p.String ] }
     ~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:18:10 - error TS1146: Declaration expected.

18   @define { save_name: [ p.String ] }
  
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:5:14 - error TS2515: Non-abstract class 'NewSaveView' does not implement inherited abstract member 'doit' from class 'ActionToolView'.

5 export class NewSaveView extends ActionToolView
               ~~~~~~~~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '#'.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
    ~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:10 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'is'.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
           ~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:13 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'executed'.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
              ~~~~~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'when'.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
                       ~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:27 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'the'.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
                            ~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:31 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'button'.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
                                ~~~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:38 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'is'.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
                                       ~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:7:41 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'clicked'.

7   # this is executed when the button is clicked
                                          ~~~~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:12:3 - error TS4020: 'extends' clause of exported class 'CustomSaveTool' has or is using private name 'default_view'.

12   default_view: NewSaveView
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:13:3 - error TS4020: 'extends' clause of exported class 'CustomSaveTool' has or is using private name 'type'.

13   type: "CustomSaveTool"
     ~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:15:3 - error TS4020: 'extends' clause of exported class 'CustomSaveTool' has or is using private name 'tool_name'.

15   tool_name: "Save"
     ~~~~~~~~~
HTML 1.4 copy.py:CustomSaveTool.ts:16:3 - error TS4020: 'extends' clause of exported class 'CustomSaveTool' has or is using private name 'icon'.

16   icon: "bk-tool-icon-save"
     ~~~~
```

and this is my code

```
from bokeh.models import Tool
from bokeh.core.properties import String
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show

JS_CODE_SAVE = """
import * as p from "core/properties"
import {ActionTool, ActionToolView} from "models/tools/actions/action_tool"

export class NewSaveView extends ActionToolView

  # this is executed when the button is clicked
  doit: () ->
    @plot_view.save(@model.save_name)

export class CustomSaveTool extends ActionTool
  default_view: NewSaveView
  type: "CustomSaveTool"

  tool_name: "Save"
  icon: "bk-tool-icon-save"

  @define { save_name: [ p.String ] } """

class CustomSaveTool(Tool):
    """
    Save a plot with a custom name.
    Usage: CustomSaveTool(save_name = name)
    """
    __implementation__ = JS_CODE_SAVE
    name = String()

tools = [CustomSaveTool(name = 'custom name 1')]
        
graph1 = figure(
    title="plottest",
    tools=tools,
    sizing_mode="stretch_width",
    x_axis_label='X_axislabel',
    y_axis_label='Y_axislabel'
)
```

Comment: The string value of `JS_CODE_SAVE` does not appear to be valid JS code, while the variable name indicates it should be. And the errors all seem to stem from this not being valid JS (or TS) syntax.

Comment: i try to solve the synatx error but still another errors come up , I think this way to modify tool in bokeh not working correctly

Comment: Do you know that bokeh offers you other options to export a figure with the option to add a file name? See [section 7](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/first_steps/first_steps_7.html#first-steps-7-displaying-and-exporting) in the first steps guide. And as far as I know opens the lastest version of bokeh a pop-up window and asking for a file name if you click on the save tool. If you have not the lastest version, maybe an upgrade will solve your issue.

Comment: the solution was just to update the library and see the update documentation ,thanks you all for your help